# Class with a sometimes unused property

Tags: c#, object-oriented, classes, properties

From times to times I stumble over the following situation:

I have got a class with a property that's only used if another property has a particular value, for instance:

```
public enum enum_ConnectionType
{
    Local,
    Server
}

public class Session
{
    private enum_ConnectionType _connectionType;
    private string _serverName; // It only makes sense if _connectionType == enum_ConnectionType.Server

    public Session(enum_ConnectionType connectionType, string serverName)
    {
        _connectionType = connectionType;
        _serverName = serverName;
    }
}
```

There's something that does not feel right to me. 
What is your common approach on this kind of situations?

**EDIT**

I think both Jeff and Leonid answers are valid depending on the situation.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: C#, I just updated the tags, but I believe this is a common situation for most of the oop languages.

Comment: I'd just change the line `_serverName = serverName;` to be `_serverName = _connectionType == enum_ConnectionType.Server ? serverName : null;` . So an instance of `Session` is internally consistent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would do this using an interface and polymorphism to represent this:

```
public interface ISession
{
    void DoSomething();

    // Add your properties / method definitions
}

public class ServerSession : ISession
{
     private readonly string _serverName;

     public ServerSession(string serverName)
     {
         _serverName = serverName;
     }

     public void DoSomething()
     {
         // Some Code
     }

     // Implement interface contracts
}

public class OtherSession : ISession
{

     public void DoSomething()
     {
         // Some Code
     }

     // Implement interface contracts
}
```

Then you would use it something like this:

```
public DoSomethingWithSession(ISession session)
{
     session.DoSomething();
}

foo.DoSomethingWithSession(new ServerSession());
```

If there is commonality between ISession implementations, you could base class that out, then inherit from that.

Comment: This was my initial thought, thanks for posting.

Comment: Did you really use “base class” as a verb? :-)

Comment: lol...guess I did :)

Comment: While this is valid, depending on what the class is doing it may also be over-engineering.

Comment: This is not over-engineering. It's paying your technical debt upfront.

Session class, as it is, doesn't have any public behavior.
You either put `doSomething()`s on it, or `getSomething()`.

If you go `doSomething` route your Session class is peppered with `if(connectionType==LOCAL)` conditionals.
If you go `getSomething` route, it is worse; everywhere `Session` class is used is polluted with the said conditionals.

Moreover, each time you forget the conditional you get a `NullReferenceException` or what's its name.

Comment: Only case you can cleanly ignore this is a case where you set `serverName` to some default value, say `localhost` and everything just works. (As in *Substitution Principle*)
Of course, in that case, having a `ConnectionType` type-code is also over-engineering.

Comment: @abuzittin gillifirca, my answer is different from this one (and it is a good thing) and I admit that there is no perfect answer for "it depends" (on what you are doing). To address your concern for having ugly code -  there is a way to factor out the commonly used logic into a helper function such that the probability of a bug goes down. If my project was small, I would probably start as simple as possible. Once a class can no longer cope with everything that is demanded from it, I think it is a good time to modify the class hierarchy.

Comment: Helper functions drive me nuts.  They totally undermine the power of OOD and OOP.  Even in a small project, extract classes to remove if/then/else is worth way more for readability and simplicity than helper functions.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca I disagree that its not overengineered.  The problems you are worrying about in your solution may never become problems because the class may never become as complex as you're anticipating.  The other answer to this question is perfectly acceptable if there are only minor and easily implemented differences between a local and remote connection.

Answer (score 5):

There is a different way, supplemented by documentation. One can say that it goes against OOP, one can also say that it keeps things simple and favors composition over inheritance. Here `serverName = null` is a convention for local connection. This approach condenses the entire state to a single string value.

This is not the only way. Sometimes this is a bad approach, sometimes a good one - depends on how big your architecture is and what your use cases are.

```
public class Session
{
    private readonly string serverName;

    /// Document me!    
    public Session() : this(null)
    {
    }

    /// Document me!
    public Session(string serverName)
    {
        // Assert serverName is not null or whitespace
        this.serverName = serverName;
    }

    /// Document me!    
    public bool IsLocalConnection
    {
        // Make sure that it is not whitespace
        return this.ServerName == null;
    }

    /// Document me!
    public string ServerName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.serverName;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why not just have two CreateSession methods, one which takes a string the other which takes nothing?  Seems like the Session itself is the only thing that should care if its local or not.  Otherwise I think this is the best answer.

Comment: @Andy, you are right. I took your feedback and simplified my code, albeit in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 2):

From a memory perspective I wouldn't worry.  A few extra machine words in your class is unlikely to make a difference, and allocators out there tend to pad upwards anyway.

From an OO perspective, you can always make a subclass to add the field.